# Issue with the product count on the pagination not working on product listing page

Tags: magento-2.1, product-list

I am working on a magento 2 store and I am getting this weird issue.

**The total count of the product on the pagination doesn't match the total number of product displayed on the category page.**

Below screenshot would make my issue very clear.

[image]

Is anyone facing similar issue and has the fix please suggest. I'm not sure from where to start figuring this out.

What I have tried out:

- I have completely re indexed the store.
- I don't see such issue listed on magento2 issue github so not sure if it is generic issue of magento 2.
- I tried upgrading to latest version of magento

Can anyone suggest anything?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I think Your magento instance is not showing all the products from that particular category. We had the same issue on two different stores even after running indexer.

Do this : 
Navigate to class `Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\AbstractAction`
and change `RANGE_CATEGORY_STEP` constant from 500 to 5000;

now run the indexers. Now it should show the correct count.

I don't know precisely why this works. But I traced the indexer query to this particular line. You never face this issue on  magento with less number of categories. With  500 as the constant value, catalog_category_product_index is not fully built. Please let me know what happens